# How to use eloquent builder to fetch results twice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

How do I use one query builder to fetch results twice? With `Carbon` I have use `CarbonImmutable` to achieve this but with eloquent, one fetch is affecting the others down the line.

Here is the code.

```php
$expenses = PropertyExpense::with(['bill'])
            ->where('contractor_id', $supplier);

/* I run this to get balance brought forward */

$oldDebits = $expenses->whereDate('txn_date', '<', $start)
            ->sum('billed'); //here I get actual bbf value.

/* Then I run this to get the debits for the start and end period */
$debits = $expenses
            ->whereDate('txn_date', '>=', $start)
            ->whereDate('txn_date', '<=', $end)
            ->get(); //Here I get empty array. Which should not be the case.
```

When I remove the $oldDebits Section, I get the Collection of all debits as expected.
I have even rewritten the code to temporarily assign expenses to another variable before executing the sum to no avail. Here.

```php
$olderDebits = $expenses;
$oldDebits = $olderDebits->whereDate('txn_date', '<', $start)->sum('billed');
```

When I ran this, am still getting the same results: correct $oldDebits and an empty collection for $debits.

Any assistance?

Am using `Laravel V9` and `PHP 8.1`.

Comment: That is because you add the whereDate to the `$expenses` variable, so the where statement from "oldDebits" is still present when you add the where statements for "debits". What you might be looking for is a scope https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: To debug this You can print both queries to see what is going on.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz there is only one "query", that is changed and executed a second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you ->whereDate() on to the same variable which is `$expenses`.

In your case, you should clone the query builder before execute it.

Such as

```
$expenses = PropertyExpense::with(['bill'])->where('contractor_id', $supplier);

$oldDebits = (clone $expenses)->whereDate('txn_date', '<', $start)->sum('billed');

$debits = (clone $expenses)
            ->whereDate('txn_date', '>=', $start)
            ->whereDate('txn_date', '<=', $end)
            ->get();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. It works as expected.